# $\angle ABD=38°, \angle DBC=46°, \angle BCA=22°, \angle ACD=48°,$ then find $\angle BDA$

Tags: geometry

I'm interested in Langley's problem.

I've been struggling to solve the following question and I've just got the result by a tedious calculation using Euler's formula $e^{i\pi x/{180}}=\cos{x°}+\sin{x°}$.

In a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, letting $\angle ABD=38°, \angle DBC=46°, \angle BCA=22°, \angle ACD=48°,$ then find $\angle BDA$.

The answer I got is $\angle BDA=18°$. Then, here is my question.

**Question**: Could you show me how to prove this by the way of elementary geometry?

I've tried, but it seems very difficult.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Actually, if you draw a random convex quadrilateral, it's pretty easy. It's basic arithmetic and division in triangles. Though in the end,there's a rule I don't remember. But I did get every other angle except the last two.

Comment: Indeed, drawing the diagonals of such a quadrilateral gives (notwithstanding some calculation error) the central angle opening up to side **AD** as *112* degrees. so m<BDA + m<CAD = 180 - 112...

Comment: I think the idea is: You need to find $\sin 38^{\circ}, 46^{\circ}, 22^{\circ}$ and $\sin 48^{\circ}, 18^{\circ}$.

Comment: @harrypham: using trigonometric functions is not elementary geometry. I have a proof using explicit coordinates in terms of tangens, but this isn't elementary either.

Comment: Why did you use degrees if you used Euler's formula? Any excuse is a good excuse to use radians!

Comment: Is there a precise definition for elementary geometry? Congruent triangle , compass and ruler constructions, what else?

Comment: @MvG: I just checked [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles) and it links to [this page](http://www.gensu.co.jp/saito/challenge/3circumcenter_en.html) linking to [this PDF translation](http://www.gensu.co.jp/saito/challenge/pdf/3circumcenter_d20161211.pdf) of [the first elementary geometry solution to the problem](https://note.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/n365238) found in 2015 October! I have not read it but it looks incredible! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I could not. **Most** angles can be found through basic Geometry, but the last two (including the desired $\angle BDA$) will require Trigonometry. I did try a system of equations based on $(1)$ and $(4)$, but it got to $68^\circ=B\hat{D}A+68^\circ-B\hat{D}A\iff0=0$:   nothing useful.

Let's name the point of the crossing diagonals $O$.

$$
C\hat{O}B=180^\circ-B\hat{C}A-D\hat{B}C=112^\circ\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
B\hat{O}A=180^\circ-C\hat{O}B=68^\circ\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)\\
D\hat{O}C=B\hat{O}A=68^\circ\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)\\
A\hat{O}D=C\hat{O}B=112^\circ\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)\\
C\hat{D}B=180^\circ-A\hat{C}D-D\hat{O}C=64^\circ\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
B\hat{A}C=180^\circ-B\hat{O}A-A\hat{B}D=74^\circ\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
$$

(the numbers between parentheses are the basic Geometry rules used - referred below. I use the hat to refer to the vertice of the angle, and the 3-letter combination to refer to the amplitude of the respective angle, being the letters' order always counterclockwise)

$(1)$ the sum of the internal angles of any [triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle) is $180^\circ$
$(2)$ [supplementary angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_angles) sum to $180^\circ$
$(3)$ [vertically opposite angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertically_opposite_angles) are equal in amplitude
$(4)$ the sum of the internal angles of any [quadrilateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) is $360^\circ$

By $(1)$ (and $(4)$ works too) we know $68^\circ=D\hat{A}C+B\hat{D}A$, however, neither algebra nor basic Geometry take us any further (I thought there was a rule in Geometry for this, however, it requires the existence of some parallel lines, like the ones in a trapezoid).

The way harder method you used requires Trigonometry, so you certainly know all the rest (I can add it, but you didn't request it, and I'm a little rusty in that area).